# Is it legal to "troll" spammers?

Tags: united-states, is-x-legal, oregon

If a spammer sends me an email advertising a service, is it legal for me to reply acting like I'm interested in the service, have a fairly long conversation about it, and then say "no thanks" when they send me an estimate?

Comment: One comedian oppenly claims to make it for laughs (and also for material for his gags): https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=james+veitch+spam+email

Comment: Have you ever walked into a store, been initially interested in something, then decided not to buy it?  Do you think changing your mind is illegal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes

Yes, telling lies is generally not unlawful, much less criminal, as long as you did not intend to profit by them, and there is no specific law violated (for example it is a crime to lie to a law enforcement officer about matters materiel to an ongoing investigation).

Attempting to get the scammer to send you money on false pretenses, however morally justified some would consider it, is likely to constitute fraud.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to get money, just waste their time.

Comment: @Someone, though you're wasting your own time simultaneously...? :)

Comment: @paulgarrett yes, i know. :)

Comment: But if you are driving in your car, and bored, it can help pass the time...

Comment: @MichaelHall that's a very bad time to answer any email, let alone a spam email.

Comment: I meant spam phone calls...  FYI, I played an email scammer once for about two weeks, and actually conned them into sending me $50 as a "show of good faith" to ensure I could trust them enough to send him $300!

Comment: @MichaelHall I didn't get any money, but I did get an email spammer to send me an estimate for developing an email spam filter!